# Best design to show the price for different combination

Tags: javascript

I have an ecommerce site and a product can have three variants. This is what I have

```
color | size   | material | price
blue  | medium | leather  | $21.00
blue  | large  | leather  | $27.00
blue  | large  | cotton   | $47.00
white | large  | cotton   | $57.00
```

On the browser I have three drop downs:

```
color   : blue/white
size    : medium/large
material: leather/cotton
```

When buyer changes an option then I need to show updated price.

On server side I would have done a database query to get the price. On browser I have to use JavaScript to get the price. What is the best way to accomplish it.

One solution was to keep a giant hash in Javascript

```
{"blue-medium-leather" : 21.00}
```

This strategy will work. However I am wondering if there is a better solution in JavaScript that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `2^3 = 8` combinations. In this case I would suggest nested structure like this:

```
var prices = {
    medium: {
        leather : {
            blue: 21.0,
            white: //...
        },
        cotton: {
            //...
        }
    },
    large: {
        leather : {
            blue: 27.0,
            white: //...
        },
        cotton: {
            blue: 47.0,
            white: 57.0
        }

    }
}
```

Querying is surprisingly simple:

```
var price = prices.large.cotton.white;  //57.0
```

Or if you fetch string values from drop-downs (in jQuery):

```
var size = $('#size').val();
var material = $('#material').val();
var color = $('#color').val();
var price = prices[size][material][color];
```

Obviously with every combination the size of this object grows exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

You can't possibly keep the database in JS, can you? What you need is a webservice that you pass the color, size and material and the server returns the price. You can call that from JavaScript using Ajax

Comment: Yes making an AJAX call every single time one changes a value in drop down is one option. But that seems a bit too heavy to me. We should be able to keep all this info on client side. A product has at most 30 variations. 30 should be manageable on client side.

Comment: @nodejs99: Sure, but you'll still need to make a request to get the data right? Aren't the prices stored in a database? Otherwise you need to change your JS every time prices change. Maybe a single request that fetches all the data in the format suggested by Tomasz, or have the server side embedit in the HTML.